# Php переменная обрезает значение на знаке "&"

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

методом пост из js скрипта передается значение переменной в php файл. В переменной находится html код таблицы. 
Значение присваивается: $userTovar = $_POST['usertovar'];
Далее этот код отсылается письмом на почту, но приходит только часть кода, которая находится до знака "&". Как решить эту проблему, ребят?

Comment: проверте все ли пришло что надо `var_dump($userTovar)`.

Comment: php скрипт в отдельном файле, обращение к нему ajax. Как в таком случае проверить?
По крайней мере в js значение полное и правильное - alert-ом проверял.

Comment: @BigBreadman, alert до того как отправили или после?

Comment: alert в условии: если письмо отравилось - то он показывается.

Answer (score 3):

Пихать в переменную хтмл-код для отправки его на сервер -- провальная идея, поскольку в этом коде может встретится знак амперсанда, который обрежет переменную. Правильнее создать объект, сериализовать его в жсон-строку и в таком виде отдавать. 
Ну а в качестве костыля могу рекомендовать так:

```
var uri = "<html><body><p>&nbsp;</p></body></html>";  
var usertovar = encodeURIComponent(uri);
```

Comment: Костыль подошел! Спасибо огромное, сидел уже и не знал что делать, опыта не хватает)

Comment: слева от моего ответа, там где значки рейтинга вверх и вниз -- ниже есть круглящок с птичкой, называется "принять ответ", таки щелкните его, я вас прошу :)